# Android show toast before methdod

Tags: android

Because you must include a legal notice when using google maps on android I added the following code to my fragment:

```
 //in oncreate view method
_noticeMaps.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()
    {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view)
        {
            Toast.makeText(getActivity().getApplicationContext(), "Loading", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            showLegalNotice();
        }
 });


 public void showLegalNotice(){
    _legalNotice = GooglePlayServicesUtil.getOpenSourceSoftwareLicenseInfo(getActivity());
    AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity());
    builder.setTitle("Legal Notice");
    builder.setMessage(_legalNotice);
    AlertDialog dialog = builder.create();
    dialog.show();
}
```

Because the legal notice takes a long time to be placed in the setMessage the app shows the dialog after a few seconds (5+). Thats why i added the toast before the showLegalNotice to notice the user that its loading. However the toast shows after the dialog is loaded. Why isnt the toast showing before the dialog is loading? I call showLegalNotice AFTER i create the toast. **I know i can fix it with threads but I want to understand why the toast is showing after the dialog is created.**

Comment: That's because UI thread. is busy getting the legal notice and toast also works on UI thread. Unless UI thread is free you wont see the toast. Use a progress bar instead.

Comment: @Rohit5k2 But i request the legal notice after i show the toast, why isnt show toast called first than?

Comment: I believe thats because before UI could update itself legal notice query start executing. Might be better explanation for this. But this is what happens.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The best solution is to put the `legalNotice` method codes in an `AsyncTask`. The `Toast` is shown after the dialog because **you are doing the heavy work on the UI thread which is making it busy** and that's why the toast is lagging behind.

If you don't know about AsyncTask, you can learn about it [here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html). **You can show the Toast in the `preExecute()` method of the AsyncTask.** It will be guaranteed that the toast will be shown before any other action is taken.

**UPDATE**

Yes, you are right. The code is run in a sequential manner so the `Toast` should have been shown before the method runs. But try to think in a different way.

The Toast is an system UI component. You call **show()** on toast and your code moves to the next heavy or long-running task almost instantly.

There is **always a slight delay** for the toasts to be drawn or initiated on your screen and it also depends on various flavours of Android. So, before the toast starts to draw on the screen, the **UI thread gets busy or jammed** on performing a **long-running task** and looses frames.

Just when the long-running task of your method ends, the **UI thread gets free once again and is able to resume drawing the toast.** That is why, the toast is displayed, but always after the method completed its execution.

Comment: i would really like some more info on why toast is not shown before. I know i can fix it with asynctask but i dont understand why the toast isnt shown before the method call. as far as i know the code is run in order and not async

Comment: I have updated the answer with a detailed explanation. If you are satisfied, it would be great if you can accept and upvote the answer.